# Replace substring by substring in column of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas data frame `data` with several columns. One of these columns is `GEN`. This column contains german cities as strings. Some of these cities are in a bad format, meaning that they have values like `"Frankfurt a.Main"`. For every element in `data['GEN']` I would like to replace every expression of the form `"\.[A-ZÄÖÜ]"` (i.e. dot followed by upper case letter) by the corresponding expression `"\.\b[A-ZÄÖÜ]"`. For example

- `"Frankfurt a.Main"` becomes `"Frankfurt a. Main"`
- `"Frankfurt a.d.Oder"` becomes `"Frankfurt a.d. Oder"`
  and so on.

I am pretty sure that `pandas.Series.str.contains` and `pandas.Series.str.replace` are helpful here, but one of my problems is that I don't know how to put the replacement task in a form that can be used by the above functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.str.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to capture the two groups that compose a german city name in your original data and then add a whitespace between them.

Try this :

```
data['GEN'] = data['GEN'].str.replace(r'(\w+\s.*\.)(\w*)', r'\1 \2', regex=True)
```

##### # Output :

```
0      Frankfurt a. Main
1    Frankfurt a.d. Oder
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assert a dot to the left using a positive lookbehind `(?<=\.)` and match one of `[A-ZÄÖÜ]`

In the replacement use a space followed by the full match using `\g<0>`

```
import pandas as pd

pattern = r"(?<=\.)[A-ZÄÖÜ]"
items = [
    "Frankfurt a.Main",
    "Frankfurt a.d.Oder"
]
data = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["GEN"])
data['GEN'] = data['GEN'].str.replace(pattern, r' \g<0>')
print(data)
```

Output

```
                   GEN
0    Frankfurt a. Main
1  Frankfurt a.d. Oder
```